# Use NVL, GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT to check if record are same

Tags: oracle, group-by, count, having, nvl

I have 2 tables: `CUST_DETAILS` with column `CUST_REF_ID` and
`CUST_MERGE` with columns `NEW_CUST_REF_ID` and `OLD_CUST_REF_ID`, below script will check if both columns in `CUST_MERGE` having same country id with the corresponding column in `CUST_DETAILS`, and return Y, else return N

```
SELECT
   NVL
      ((SELECT 'Y' FROM DUAL WHERE EXISITS
       (
        SELECT CTRY_ID FROM CUST_DETAILS cust_dtl
        INNER JOIN CUST_MERGE cust_merge
        ON cust_dtl.CUST_REF_ID=cust_merge.NEW_CUST_REF_ID
        AND cust_dtl.CUST_REF_ID=cust_merge.OLD_CUST_REF_ID
        GROUP BY CTRY_ID
        HAVING COUNT(CTRY_ID)>1
        )),'N') AS SAME_CTRY_ID
FROM DUAL;
```

The data in both tables are all having same country_id, meaning expected result is 'Y'. But 'N' returned for now, unless if I change condition from `AND` to `OR`, then it work as what expected,even the subquery also return with correct country ID

Sample Data

TABLE CUST_MERGE

```
 NEW_CUST_REF_ID                        OLD_CUST_REF_ID

 B5000                                   B6000

 B5000                                   A6000
```

TABLE CUST_DETAILS

```
 CUST_REF_ID                CTRY_ID  
 B5000                       US

 B6000                       US   

 A6000                       JP
```

When execute first line in `CUST_MERGE`, B5000 and B6000, return Y, as ctry_id are same (US)
When execute second line in `CUST_MERGE`, B5000 and A6000, return N, as ctry_id are different (US,JP)

Comment: You are comparing the same row.  From what I understand you want to join twice to `CUST_MERGE` and compare two different rows. Does that sound right?

Comment: There has multiple rows in `CUST_MERGE` but i want to compare columns in same row.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @San, samle data and expected result added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query to get the flag:

```
SQL> WITH  CUST_MERGE( NEW_CUST_REF_ID, OLD_CUST_REF_ID) AS
  2    (SELECT 'B5000', 'B6000' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 'A5000', 'A6000' FROM dual),
  4  CUST_DETAILS (CUST_REF_ID,CTRY_ID) AS
  5   ( SELECT 'B5000', 'US' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 'B6000', 'US' FROM dual UNION ALL
  7     SELECT 'A5000', 'UK' FROM dual UNION ALL
  8     SELECT 'A6000', 'JP' FROM dual)
----------------------------
----End of Data Preparation
----------------------------
  9  SELECT cm.new_cust_ref_id,
 10         cm.old_cust_ref_id,
 11         dc.ctry_id,
 12         dc1.ctry_id,
 13         CASE
 14           WHEN dc.ctry_id = dc1.ctry_id THEN
 15            'Y'
 16           ELSE
 17            'N'
 18         END AS flag
 19    FROM cust_merge cm
 20    JOIN cust_details dc
 21      ON cm.new_cust_ref_id = dc.cust_ref_id
 22    JOIN cust_details dc1
 23      ON cm.old_cust_ref_id = dc1.cust_ref_id;
```

Output

```
NEW_CUST_REF_ID OLD_CUST_REF_ID CTRY_ID CTRY_ID FLAG
--------------- --------------- ------- ------- ----
B5000           B6000           US      US      Y
A5000           A6000           UK      JP      N
```

The query for your tables comes out to be

```
SELECT cm.new_cust_ref_id,
       cm.old_cust_ref_id,
       dc.ctry_id, 
       dc1.ctry_id,
       CASE
         WHEN dc.ctry_id = dc1.ctry_id THEN
          'Y'
         ELSE
          'N'
       END AS flag
  FROM cust_merge cm
  JOIN cust_details dc
    ON cm.new_cust_ref_id = dc.cust_ref_id
  JOIN cust_details dc1
    ON cm.old_cust_ref_id = dc1.cust_ref_id;
```

**Update**: With the new data, results are as expected:

```
SQL> WITH  CUST_MERGE( NEW_CUST_REF_ID, OLD_CUST_REF_ID) AS
  2    (SELECT 'B5000', 'B6000' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 'B5000', 'A6000' FROM dual),
  4  CUST_DETAILS (CUST_REF_ID,CTRY_ID) AS
  5   ( SELECT 'B5000', 'US' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 'B6000', 'US' FROM dual UNION ALL
  7     SELECT 'A6000', 'JP' FROM dual)
  8  SELECT cm.new_cust_ref_id,
  9         cm.old_cust_ref_id,
 10         dc.ctry_id,
 11         dc1.ctry_id,
 12         CASE
 13           WHEN dc.ctry_id = dc1.ctry_id THEN
 14            'Y'
 15           ELSE
 16            'N'
 17         END AS flag
 18    FROM cust_merge cm
 19    JOIN cust_details dc
 20      ON cm.new_cust_ref_id = dc.cust_ref_id
 21    JOIN cust_details dc1
 22      ON cm.old_cust_ref_id = dc1.cust_ref_id;
```

Output:

```
NEW_CUST_REF_ID OLD_CUST_REF_ID CTRY_ID CTRY_ID FLAG
--------------- --------------- ------- ------- ----
B5000           B6000           US      US      Y
B5000           A6000           US      JP      N
```

Comment: The `CASE..WHEN` working fine, i got 4 'Y' from my actual data. I have another concern as my data in `CUST_MERGE` just 2 rows. Is it possible to make the comparision run row by row? Maybe using  `ROWNUM` to just return 2 'Y' ? I am working in 11g

Comment: But this query is returning only 2 rows, you can see that in the output, Is there any other specific case? If yes then post some sample data.

Comment: Sorry, in my `CUST_MERGE`, both `NEW_CUST_REF_ID` are same, i updated the sample data.

Comment: Still the query returns the expected results, you will get two rows one with flag value `Y` and another with flag value `N`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
m.CUST_REF_ID
FROM
CUST_MERGE M
INNER JOIN 
CUST_DETAILS D1 on 
(m.CUST_REF_ID=d1.NEW_CUST_REF_ID)
INNER JOIN 
CUST_DETAILS D2 on 
(m.CUST_REF_ID=d2.OLD_CUST_REF_ID)
WHERE d1.CTRY_ID=d2.CTRY_ID
```

Wrap that up in your Y/N code. (I think)
or maybe

```
SELECT 
crid
from
(
SELECT
OLD_CUST_REF_ID crid
from CUST_MERGE
UNION ALL
SELECT
NEW_CUST_REF_ID 
from CUST_MERGE
) as x inner join
CUST_DETAILS on x.crid=CUST_DETAILS.CUST_REF_ID 
group by CRID
HAVING (COUNT DISTINCT CTRY_ID)>1
```